# Getting the closest weekday to today in from a matrix (weekdays in ddd format)

Tags: c#, datetime, dayofweek

I've been given a bit of a head ache when I was asked to see if i could get a simple solution to a problem at work.

This is the current situation:

- We have a date (Mostly todays date) from which I can easily get the Weekday parameter using
  dEarliest.ToString("ddd");
- In a database we have a register of which day a certain task is to be performed with the weekdays stored as "ddd" format (i.e Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu etc).

And, the problem, How can I get which day in the database records that are the closest to today?
I've been sitting here trying to figure it out with some "smart" SQL query, but I just don't know how to wrap my head around it.

I was thinking enum:s, but I'm not sure if that'd work, and if it would, how? I'm quite new at c#
hence the, probably, stupid question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you provide a specific example?  You're looking forward? Backwards? Both directions?  Does it matter if the closest day was a week ago, or are you only looking at days of the week and not the actual date?

Comment: Are you looking at dates or days? Correct me if I'm wrong. Your database has some task and an associated DAY? For example, "Meeting #1" -> Mon, "Meeting #2" -> Wed. And you want to look at TODAY and find the next DAY  that's in your database?

Comment: Hi, yes, it's all about DAYs, not dates. And I only look forwards. So, let's say it's Monday today and the next valid day for that activity is on Thursday I need to get that DAY. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to make a comparrison between the `DateTime`'s `DayOfWeek` value (the property `DayOfWeek` is of type `enum DayOfWeek`) and the output of SQL Server's `DATEPART` function.

For example, if you wanted to get all the tasks for yesterday, you might do this in C#:

`int yesterday = ((int)(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek))-1;`

and then pass that value into a SQL statement that does this:

`SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE DATEPART(weekday, <column_name>) = (@yesterday+1)`

The `@yesterday+1` part is because C#'s enum uses 0-6 for the days while SQL Server uses 1-7 (both uses Sunday as the first index).

Comment: Hi nateirvin, this won't work since the day value in the database is stored as nvarchar(3) and contains values like "Mon","Tue","Wed" etc, in the same manner as the dEarliest.ToString("ddd") will generate.